# Unable to run eletrode app-getting error

Tags: node.js, npm, react-redux, hapi.js

I'm following the quick start guide of eletrode
(http://www.electrode.io/docs/what_is_electrode.html).  In between the following error I'm getting when running command npm install. Tried multiple option to solve it. But could not succeeded on it. If anyone have solution, just let me know.
Thank you for your time & appreciate your help.

The error code is metioned below & I'm using ubunut 16.04 & node verion 8.9.1

```
    electrode-archetype-opt-inferno@0.2.2 preinstall /media/prince/New Volume/tutorial/tutorial_project/test/myapp/node_modules/electrode-archetype-react-app-dev/node_modules/electrode-archetype-opt-inferno
    > node optional-check.js

    electrode-archetype-opt-inferno: no archetype config found - skipping install

    > electrode-archetype-opt-inferno@0.1.1 preinstall /media/prince/New Volume/tutorial/tutorial_project/test/myapp/node_modules/electrode-archetype-opt-inferno
    > node optional-check.js

    electrode-archetype-opt-inferno: no archetype config found - skipping install

    > electrode-archetype-opt-inferno@0.2.2 preinstall /media/prince/New Volume/tutorial/tutorial_project/test/myapp/node_modules/electrode-archetype-react-app/node_modules/electrode-archetype-opt-inferno
    > node optional-check.js

    electrode-archetype-opt-inferno: no archetype config found - skipping install
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: electrode-archetype-opt-inferno@0.2.2 (node_modules/electrode-archetype-react-app-dev/node_modules/electrode-archetype-opt-inferno):
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: electrode-archetype-opt-inferno@0.2.2 preinstall: `node optional-check.js`
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: electrode-archetype-opt-inferno@0.1.1 (node_modules/electrode-archetype-opt-inferno):
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: electrode-archetype-opt-inferno@0.1.1 preinstall: `node optional-check.js`
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: electrode-archetype-opt-inferno@0.2.2 (node_modules/electrode-archetype-react-app/node_modules/electrode-archetype-opt-inferno):
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: electrode-archetype-opt-inferno@0.2.2 preinstall: `node optional-check.js`
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

    up to date in 21.423s


    $ clap dev
    [15:33:43] xclap version 0.2.21 at CWD/node_modules/xclap
    [15:33:43] NodeJS version v9.4.0 at /usr/local/bin/node
    [15:33:43] CWD is /media/prince/New Volume/tutorial/tutorial_project/test/app2
    [15:33:43] Loaded CWD/xclap.js
    [15:33:43] Added CWD/~/.bin to PATH
    [15:33:43] Process dev's dependency serial array [".remove-log-files",".development-env",".clean.build",".mk-dist-dir"]
    [15:33:43] -Execute electrode/.remove-log-files as function
    [15:33:43] >Done Execute electrode/.remove-log-files as function (1 ms)
    [15:33:43] .Execute electrode/.development-env as function
    [15:33:43] >Done Execute electrode/.development-env as function (0 ms)
    [15:33:43] -Process electrode/.clean.build serial array [".clean.dist",".clean.dll"]
    [15:33:43] ..Execute electrode/.clean.dist as function
    [15:33:43] >>Done Execute electrode/.clean.dist as function (5 ms)
    [15:33:43] --Execute electrode/.clean.dll as function
    [15:33:43] >>Done Execute electrode/.clean.dll as function (0 ms)
    [15:33:43] >Done Process electrode/.clean.build serial array [".clean.dist",".clean.dll"] (9 ms)
    [15:33:43] .Execute electrode/.mk-dist-dir as function
    [15:33:43] >Done Execute electrode/.mk-dist-dir as function (2 ms)
    [15:33:43] Done Process dev's dependency serial array [".remove-log-files",".development-env",".clean.build",".mk-dist-dir"] (15 ms)
    [15:33:43] Process electrode/dev serial array [".webpack-dev",["wds.dev","server-watch","generate-service-worker"]]
    [15:33:43] .Execute electrode/.webpack-dev as function
    [15:33:43] >Done Execute electrode/.webpack-dev as function (0 ms)
    [15:33:43] -Process electrode/dev.S concurrent array ["wds.dev","server-watch","generate-service-worker"]
    [15:33:43] ..Execute electrode/wds.dev webpack-dev-server --watch --watch-aggregate-timeout 2000 --config CWD/~/electrode-archetype-react-app-dev/config/webpack/webpack.config.dev.js --progress --colors --port 2992 --host localhost
    [15:33:43] --Execute electrode/generate-service-worker as function
    [15:33:43] ..Process server-watch's dependency serial array [".init-bundle.valid.log"]
    [15:33:43] >>Done Execute electrode/generate-service-worker as function (2 ms)
    [15:33:43] ---Execute electrode/.init-bundle.valid.log as function
    [15:33:43] >>>Done Execute electrode/.init-bundle.valid.log as function (1 ms)
    [15:33:43] >>Done Process server-watch's dependency serial array [".init-bundle.valid.log"] (3 ms)
    [15:33:43] ..Execute electrode/server-watch as function
    [nodemon] 1.17.1
    [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
    [nodemon] watching: .etmp/bundle.valid.log /media/prince/New Volume/tutorial/tutorial_project/test/app2/src/server/**/* /media/prince/New Volume/tutorial/tutorial_project/test/app2/config/**/*
    info: APP_SRC_DIR set to src/
    module.js:557
    throw err;
    ^

    Error: Cannot find module '/media/prince/New'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at requireConfig (/media/prince/New Volume/tutorial/tutorial_project/test/app2/node_modules/webpack/bin/convert-argv.js:97:18)
    at /media/prince/New Volume/tutorial/tutorial_project/test/app2/node_modules/webpack/bin/convert-argv.js:104:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (/media/prince/New Volume/tutorial/tutorial_project/test/app2/node_modules/webpack/bin/convert-argv.js:102:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/media/prince/New Volume/tutorial/tutorial_project/test/app2/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js:223:50)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    [15:33:46] >>Failed Execute electrode/wds.dev webpack-dev-server --watch --watch-aggregate-timeout 2000 --config CWD/~/electrode-archetype-react-app-dev/config/webpack/webpack.config.dev.js --progress --colors --port 2992 --host localhost (2.63 sec)
    [15:33:46] >>Done Execute electrode/server-watch as function (2.62 sec)
    [15:33:46] >Done Process electrode/dev.S concurrent array ["wds.dev","server-watch","generate-service-worker"] (2.63 sec)
    [15:33:46] Done Process electrode/dev serial array [".webpack-dev",["wds.dev","server-watch","generate-service-worker"]] (2.63 sec)
    Execution Failed - Errors: 
    1  shell cmd 'webpack-dev-server --watch --watch-aggregate-timeout 2000 --config /media/prince/New Volume/tutorial/tutorial_project/test/app2/node_modules/electrode-archetype-react-app-dev/config/webpack/webpack.config.dev.js --progress --colors --port 2992 --host localhost' exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I have come across the problem and took two days to solve it.
Here my solution come

1. **Please do not name files and directories with spaces** mentioned by jchip in github.
   (https://github.com/electrode-io/electrode/issues/737#issuecomment-369421380)
2. Solution command  I used

   sudo nvm install 8.9.1

   nvm use v8.9.1

   sudo npm install -g electrode-ignite

   sudo npm install -g yarn

   ingnite

   clap dev